# How do I create the stub for a help page for a new function?

Tags: r, r-package

I have written up some R code, run `package.skeleton()`, edited the help pages in the `man/` directory, built and published the package.

Now I am working on version 2 and add a few functions to the code. *How do I create stubs for their help pages?* If I run `package.skeleton(force=TRUE)`, it clobbers the help pages in `man/` I already edited for version 1.

Of course I could save a backup of the `man/` directory, then run `package.skeleton(force=TRUE)`, then copy the backup into `man/`, finally edit the remaining newly created stubs... but isn't there an easier way? I have looked through "Writing R extensions", but didn't find anything.

---

An MWE:

1. For version 1, our file `code_file.R` contains one line:

   ```
   foo <- function() print("foo")
   ```
2. We run

   ```
   package.skeleton(name="test",code_files="code_file.R")
   ```

   which creates a stub file `test/man/foo.Rd`.
3. We edit `test/man/foo.Rd`. (We build and publish the package, irrelevant here.)
4. For version 2, we add the following line to `code_file.R`:

   ```
   bar <- function() print("bar")
   ```
5. Now, how do we get a stub for `test/man/bar.Rd` without clobbering the existing `test/man/foo.Rd`?

Comment: Have a look at `utils::prompt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `utils::prompt()` to create a skeleton help page. See the documentation at `?prompt` for the full details.